# Why does Flask 'POST' not return a simple JSON object?

Tags: python, json, http, flask, request

I have tried to find similar questions (or documentation) with little success, so I would be *very* grateful if somebody could point me in the direction of where I have gone wrong here.

In Python 3, I have used Flask to receive HTTP requests for JSON and return them.

```
from flask import Flask, request
app=Flask(__name__, template_folder='')

@app.route('/json', methods=['POST'])
def json():
    return format(request)
```

I am using Postman to POST the following to 127.0.0.1/json (to confirm: 127.0.0.1/json works perfectly well if I just ask it to return "Hello World"):

```
{
    "test":"Hello World"
}
```

Then Postman responds with:

```
<Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/json' [POST]>
```

So far, so good. But it reports there is an "Invalid character in attribute name".

Furthermore, when I change the Python script to:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app=Flask(__name__, template_folder='')

@app.route('/json', methods=['POST'])
def json():
    return format(request.get_json())
```

The script returns "None" to Postman, despite a JSON object being POST'ed' to it.

Thanks very much to anyone who can clarify this for me. I usually try to debug myself, but this has had me really stumped for a few hours. I am sure I am doing something really stupid! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have also tried request.data() and request.json() to little success.

Comment: To confirm, have you tried printing `request.json`?

Comment: Did you try with request.data.decode() ?

Comment: @user1579970 I have just tried running your example and I see get no issues. Where are you seeing "Invalid character in attribute name"?

Comment: request.json gives "null". 

request.data.decode() gives ""{\n    \"test\":\"Hello World\"\n}"", which indicates it's received the JSON object into data. I guess I could hardcode a way to extract the data from .decode(), but not ideal. Now quite interested in why data alone or get_json() do not work.

Comment: turnip - I am seeing the error code in Postman's console. Thanks everyone for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OK, for whatever reason the JSON object was not being parsed as 'application/json', I fixed this problem:

```
return format(request.get_json(force=True))
```

the argument force=True will process the JSON anyhow.

Thank you very much everybody for your help! Hope this helps somebody else who's a bit confused...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not sending the payload as JSON from Postman.

It should look like this:

[image]

Then when you do `request.json` in your Flask app you should see the JSON. Note that it is **not request.json()**

Comment: Thanks, turnip, the odd thing is that I am. I made absolutely sure of this before posting. Will keep fiddling and report back if I find something....